# How to resume python pin from last place?

Tags: python, pyautogui

The pin in the Python code does not pick up where it left off. It does the operations and when it wants to enter the for loop 80 times, it starts from 100650 again.

```
import pyautogui
import time

try:
    while True:
        sonpin = 999999
        yenipin = 1

        pyautogui.click(1600, 570)
        if sonpin != yenipin:
            for i in range(80):
                pin = 100650
                pin = pin + 1
                time.sleep(0.21)
                pyautogui.typewrite(str(pin), interval=0.15)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                pin = pin+1
                time.sleep(0.1)
                pyautogui.click(1600, 570)
                print(pin)

        pyautogui.click(1900, 1000)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(1445, 320)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(1445, 320)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(1800, 590)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(1900, 970)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        pyautogui.click(1770, 270)
        time.sleep(4)
        pyautogui.click(1600, 1000)
        time.sleep(0.3)
        pyautogui.click(1450, 240)
        time.sleep(0.15)
        pyautogui.typewrite("oreoswish", interval=0.1)
        pyautogui.click(1450, 300)
        time.sleep(0.15)
        pyautogui.typewrite("chudi123", interval=0.1)
        pyautogui.click(1600, 390)
        time.sleep(10)
        pyautogui.click(1825, 1000)
        time.sleep(0.35)
        pyautogui.click(1855, 85)
        time.sleep(0.35)
        pyautogui.click(1450, 265)
        time.sleep(0.35)
        pyautogui.click(1850, 205)
        time.sleep(0.35)
        pyautogui.click(1850, 205)


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\n")
```

What I want to do is to increase from 100650 to 80 times and continue from 100650+80 when I do the operations and enter the for loop again.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just move the line `pin =  100650` to outside the `while` loop?

Comment: It was like that before, but in the last case it was still pin = 100650 and 100651, 100652...100730 continued

Comment: So you want it to rest back to 100650, but only after the 80 steps? then you need to make the range go to something like `40` in the for loop, and take the `pin = 100650` and move it outside the for loop, like in the beginning of the while loop, for example

Comment: Clarification on expected behavior is needed as the intention of the code isn't clear.  `sonpin` and `yenipin` are both set to constant values at the start of the `while` loop and never modified, but the `for` loop you mention runs once (with `range(1)`) as long as sonpin != yenipin, which is always true.  Also, all of the code after the for loop with `pyautogui.click()` and `time.sleep()` is not necessary to be included as part of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: No. After starting from 100650 and increasing it 80 times. It will do the necessary clicks and start counting from (100650+80)=100730

Comment: If pyautogui.click() and time.sleep() outside of the for loop are inside, the code clicks every time it increments the number. I don't want this, the number will increase 80 times, then clicks will do. @nigh_anxiety

Comment: @MehmetHanifiDağaçan I'm not saying they should be moved inside the loop - I'm saying they aren't necessary to be provided in the example code at all because they aren't relevant to the issue.  The code example should be the minimal code required to recreate the problem.

Comment: Problem solved. I put `pin`, `sonpin` and `yenipin` between `import` and `try:` and it works.